# How do I replace a tab character with the corresponding number of space characters? (in linux)

Tags: linux

I am planning on replacing all of my tab characters in a certain file with the corresponding number of space characters in a shell. Tried using tr and sed, but none seem to work out.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [expand](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/expand-invocation.html#expand-invocation)? Usage is:

```
$ expand  <FILE_WITH_TABS> > <FILE_WITH_NO_TABS>
```

You can also modify tab width using `-t` option. For example, to change from the default width to 2:

```
$ expand -t 2 <FILE_WITH_TABS> <FILE_WITH_NO_TABS>
```

Comment: sed -i s/\t/ $(while [[ $k -lt $n ]]; do echo -n " " k=$((k+1))) / $filename

This is what I'm trying to do by placing a while loop inside the replacement. But it does not seem to work. It gives out error messages. Any syntax errors I must be aware of?

Comment: I think you should start from reading up on how `bash` works.  First, it's an incorrect syntax. Second, command substitution happens *only once* before `sed` is even started so it wouldn't work anyway.